# Access method params through decorators

Tags: typescript, decorator

Iv'e started to read about [creation of decorators](https://medium.com/google-developers/exploring-es7-decorators-76ecb65fb841) and how to use them.
I was wondering if there's a way for me the access the wrapped method arguments inside the decorator function.

For example, I would like to create a decorator the log's the method name and the supplied arguments.
So far I only managed to access the method name.

```
  export function logger(target, propertyKey) {
    console.log(propertyKey); //Method name
  }

  @logger
  private fetchData(param) {
   ////
  }
```

Is there a way for me the access the "param" of the 'fetchData' method inside the decorator?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

Solved, [Link to working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kfbor8)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`target` is class prototype. In order for method parameters to be accessed during call, a method should be replaced with a wrapper:

```
  export function logger(target, propertyKey, descriptor) {
    const originalFn = target[propertyKey];
    descriptor.value = function(param) {
      console.log(param);
      return originalFn.call(this, param);
    };
  }

  ...
  @logger
  private fetchData(param) {}
  ...
```

Comment: It's not working... I've created a small stackblitz inspired by your answer:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vspdvh?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts
It does not log the param... Any ideas?

Comment: You're not calling this method. It's ngOnInit. Not onInit. You also mislabeled the question. It's TS question, and decorator implementations are different. In TS, a preferable way is to modify descriptor object, I updated the answer. You also shouldn't return `target[propertyKey]` from a decorator.

Comment: You are right, I wasn't calling ngOnInit properly. Now it works. Why shouldn't I return target[propertyKey] from a decorator ? If I remove it it doesn't work

Comment: It's expected that TS property/method decorator returns descriptor object or nothing. I'd suggest to stick to the code in the answer, that's how it's usually done.

Comment: See https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v2.9.2/lib/lib.d.ts#L1311

Comment: Iv'e updated my stackblitz and it woks as you said. Many thanks :)